# XPath (XSLT) match only specific structure

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

How do I match only a specific structure like:

```
<sandwich>
    <bacon />
    <lettuce />
    <tomato />
</sandwich>
```

I want to replace it with something like

```
<sandwich>
    <cheese />
    <bacon />
    <lettuce />
    <tomato />
    <mayo />
</sandwich>
```

But not effect any other similar "sandwiches", such as:

```
<sandwich>
    <bacon />
    <egg />
</sandwich>
```

More specifically, I have

```
<view>
    <layout>
        <sidebar>Some content and nodes</sidebar>
        <content>Some more content and nodes</content>
    </layout>
    <layout>
        <content>Some content and nodes</content>
        <sidebar>Some more content and nodes</sidebar>
    </layout>
</view>
```

And I want to transform it into:

```
<view>
    <foo>
        <bar>Some content and nodes</bar>
        <baz>Some more content and nodes</baz>
    </foo>
    <layout>
        <content>Some content and nodes</content>
        <sidebar>Some more content and nodes</sidebar>
    </layout>
</view>
```

(using XSLT)

Comment: You say "specific" - but you give no clue to what makes one sandwich/layout "specific", but not the other.

Comment: @michael.hor257k the `layout` node contains exactly 2 children, `sidebar` and `content` in that order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve it with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//layout[count(*)=2][sidebar/following-sibling::content]">
        <foo>
            <bar>
                <xsl:copy-of select="sidebar/node()" />
            </bar>
            <baz>
                <xsl:copy-of select="content/node()" />
            </baz>
        </foo>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You don't need the `//` in `//layout`.  You're matching on the `layout`, not selecting it, and the match pattern, with or without the `//`, has a higher priority than the node tests in the match pattern in the other `xsl:template`.

Comment: @TonyGraham even if `layout` wasn't in the root? (not at my desk to test)